# Ionic2 responding button clicks with a huge delay on device

Tags: android, firebase, ionic2, angularfire

In my Ionic2 app I have the following code:

```
<ion-content>
    <form (ngSubmit)="loginWithEmail()">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating >Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating >Senha</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <button ion-button type="submit" block>Login</button>
    </form>
    <button ion-button block (click)="loginWithFacebook()">Login com Facebook</button>
</ion-content>
```

The issue here is that when clicking one of these button I have a huge delay to get the response of the button clicked (more then the famous 300ms) both on my device and emulator, however, in the browser on my laptop, using `ionic serve`, i have practically no delay at all. Also both the methods loginWithEmail() and loginWithFacebook() are implemented using AngularFire and Firebase.

Comment: How do you know the button responsed?

Comment: can you share your login.ts to see the logic? because i have the login with firebase too and its working great, with no delay

Comment: Since it is doing some process in background like logging in, it might be waiting for that to get completed. Are you saying after clicking the button, the code written in the respective callback function e.g. `loginWithEmail()` is not getting executed right away and there is delay there? You can check this by putting simple `alert("Called function");` at the start of the function and see if it is getting called right away or not.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni Good tip. I'm going to try this.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if it works. :)

Comment: Ok, the function is being called, end the methods are being processed, now (After running with the console, I have fixed some minor issues that were breaking the mobile app). But yet, the result of the click is only showed after a lot of time. What intrigues me is that in the browser, it's quite fast.